# REACT REDUX Uncaught ReferenceError

Tags: reactjs, redux

```
var Provider = ReactRedux.Provider;
var connect = ReactRedux.connect;
```

i got error when calling to ReactRedux.Provider, but the error is pointing to brower.js and babel.js .

[image: error msg]

[image: my jsp]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're using CDN links. The url you provided doesn't export a valid export for what you're trying to do.

I tried a unpkg link and it worked fine.

```
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@16/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-redux@5.0.6/dist/react-redux.js"></script>
```

With these links the **ReactRedux** export exists and you can access it's components. Thus what you were trying to do will work

```
var Provider = ReactRedux.Provider;
var connect = ReactRedux.connect;
```

Comment: but i use <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-redux/4.4.5/react-redux.js" ></script>  instead of import

Comment: @OliverCheng you should edit your question and say that. I'm gonna edit my answer